# Recursive SwiftUI views

Tags: swift, recursion, core-data, swiftui

I'm unable to display a SwiftUI view that calls itself in a `ForEach` loop for some reason. The app hangs and then crashes when it tries to display this view:

```swift
struct LoopView: View {
    let loop: Loop

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(String(loop.multiplier))
                .font(.title)
            Text("x")
            VStack {
                // ### THE PROBLEM IS HERE ###
                if let loops = loop.loops {
                    ForEach(loops, id: \.id) { innerLoop in
//                        Text(String(innerLoop.multiplier)) // << This works
                        LoopView(loop: innerLoop) // << This causes the system to hang
                    }
                } else {
                    // This stuff here is fine
                    if let components = loop.components {
                        ForEach(components, id: \.id) { component in
                            ComponentView(component: component)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LoopView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let moc = DataController.preview.container.viewContext

    static var previews: some View {
        let outterLoop = Loop(context: moc)
        outterLoop.id = UUID()
        outterLoop.multiplier = 5
        outterLoop.addToInternalLoops(DataController.exampleLoop())

        // vvv Does not change outcome if commented out vvv
        outterLoop.addToInternalLoops(DataController.exampleLoop())

        return LoopView(loop: outterLoop)
    }
}
```

As per the comments, I can access the attributes of the looped item just fine, meaning there's nothing wrong with the loop and the elements can be accessed. However, I'm unable to use my `loop` recursively. `innerLoop` doesn't contain a `loop` meaning it will stop recursing after going only one level deep.

I'm using Xcode 13.2.1. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is it a try guess question about type `Loop` or `ComponentView`?

Comment: This is about `Loop`. `ComponentView` is fine.

Comment: Is `DataController.exampleLoop()` returning the same Loop object or a new one on each call?

Comment: Same one. It is being added to an `NSOrderedSet` (default Core Data one-to-many relationship). There is no difference if only one was added.

Comment: So you have a one-to-many relationship that is named `internalLoops` in one direction and `loops` in the other direction, is that correct and if so which is which?

Comment: So I have an entity called `Loop` which contains a one-to-many relation to `Components` and also to itself, `Loop`. The Core Data entity attribute is declared as `internalLoops: NSOrderedSet?`, and my custom accessor (to get `[Loop]` instead of an `NSOrderedSet`) is called `loop`. I'm recursively accessing the "loop" inside each loop object. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more debugging and found the error came from my self-referencing one-to-many entity needed an inverse reference to itself. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70500397/core-data-self-referencing-one-to-many-relationship?noredirect=1#comment124624167_70500397) for details.