# Core Data Self Referencing One-to-Many Relationship

Tags: swift, core-data, nested-lists

How do I properly implement a self-referencing one-to-many relationship in Core Data? I would like to create an entity that represents nested arrays (so like an array of arrays). So far I've created an "`Array`" entity and set it to have a one-to-many relationship `innerArrays` of type "`Array`" (which is itself). However, when I define an instance of `Array` like this (semi-pseudocode):

```swift
let outsideArray: Array
let insideArray: Array

outsideArray.innerArrays = [insideArray]
```

I get this output when reading it

```swift
outsideArray: // This is fine
    insideArray: // Correctly, an outsideArray has an insideArray
        outsideArray: // ????? insideArray's `innerArrays` is nil
            insideArray: // ?????
            .... // Continues on forever
```

Somehow the inside array's one-to-many reference is being populated with the outside array creating an infinite loop of arrays.

What is going on? I'm using Xcode 13.2.1 and Swift 5.2.

Thank you!

Comment: You create 2 relationships on your entity, one parent (to-one) and one children (to-many) and you set them as the inverse to each other.

Comment: Whoah... that's mind-bending, but it works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you @JoakimDanielson! Works great for those of us still stuck on CoreData :)